# Why SqlServer needs a big transaction log file

Tags: sql-server, transactions, sql-server-2012, sql-delete, transaction-log

I've been working in a SQLServer 2012 database for several years at work and I have always wondered about a strange thing I have observed with transaction logs. I 've been searching on Internet and StackOverflow for an explanation without success. I would like to understand what is happening before doing anything else.

The lasts days I have created a new database with default options and again I observe the same situation. The database has been defined with Simple recovery model.

The situation is simple to explain. I have a simple table with a Primary key only. This table has been created with default options (no replication, no partition, no relationship with any other tables etc..). It's just a simple and isolated table.

This table has about **380.000** rows and has a data size in disk of **70 Mb** and an index size of **23 Mb** aproximately. When I do a `DELETE FROM schema.table` of this table, the transaction log size grows until **500 Mb**. The transaction log has a size limit of 500 Mb, so the transaction finally fails. I am the only person working on this database. The initial size of the transaction log is 10 Mb and has a growth size of 10 Mb.

The question is: why SQLServer needs 500 Mb of log size to delete about 93 Mb of data (data + index)? I can't understand the reason. Of course I can make the transaction log size limit bigger. But this is my last option and before I want to understand what's happening. Also I don't want to do a `TRUNCATE TABLE` because I will need to do filtered deletions in the future with that number of rows.

**Edit:** finally I haver tried to increase the transaction log file limit size to 1 Gb. Executing the `DELETE` command it needed finally 530 Mb of size. 530 Mb to delete 93 Mb of data ? Is that normal ?

Thanks for any answer that can give me a light on it.

Comment: See here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/61974/transaction-log-usage-by-transaction and here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29829/why-does-the-transaction-log-keep-growing-or-run-out-of-space/

Comment: and here: http://sqlperformance.com/2013/03/io-subsystem/chunk-deletes

Comment: Thanks guys. I took a look at that articles but they didn't clarify me although they are clearly related to this. problem.